# Convert FAB <-> SliderButton on TapDown/TapUp

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter application, I have a floating action button (FAB), that should be converted to a [SliderButton](https://pub.dev/packages/slider_button) when pressed. After conversion, user should have an ability to drag/move slider at once, without any additional clicks, taps etc. However, when user raises his finger off the screen, SliderButton should be converted back to FAB.

I need help with an idea/architecture of such a solution, not necessarily the implementation itself.

More precisely, I would like to know how to keep and pass the information whether user is still touching the screen regardless FAB <-> SliderButton conversion. I tried to use `GestureDetector` as a wrapper for some other widget (as we cannot use `GestureDetector` neither in FAB not in Slider as they must rebuild, causing the loss of "touch information":

```
GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (_) {},
    onTapUp: (_) {},
    child: FABtoSlider(),
);
```

However, I'm not sure how to propagate such information down to FAB/Slider.

I`m new to Flutter, so if any part of my question is ambiguous - please let me know, I will provide more information.
Any help or information is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright guys, if any of you will ever meet the same problem - here is how I solved it:

At first I tried to use [SliderButton](https://pub.dev/packages/slider_button), but I met a big problem with it - it does not track the position of sliding button, making it impossible to move right after conversion. I tried to use `Transform.translate` to move the button, but it also shifted the whole slide area with it, although background was not moving, pretending I can slide to the end of it: [image]

So instead of SliderButton I have chosen [FlutterSlider](https://pub.dev/packages/another_xlider) with `GestureDetector`:

```
GestureDetector(
   onLongPressStart: (_) {
      setState(() {
         showSlider = true;
      });
   },
   onLongPressMoveUpdate: (details) {
      final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
      final localOffset = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
      final normalizedOffset = localOffset.dx / renderBox.size.width;
      setState(() {
         sliderValue = normalizedOffset.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
         if (sliderValue < 0.1) {
             // you can add some functionality here
             showSlider = false;
         }
      });
   },
   onLongPressEnd: (_) {
      setState(() {
         showSlider = false;
         sliderValue = 1;
      });
      widget.disableButtons?.call(false);
   },
   child: Stack(
      children: [
         if (!showSlider)
            FloatingActionButton(
               onPressed: () {},
               backgroundColor: Colors.red,
               child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            ),
         if (showSlider)
            Positioned(
               left: 0,
               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
               bottom: widget.bottomBarHeight - fabSize / 2,
               height: fabSize,
               child: FlutterSlider(
                  min: 0,
                  max: 1,
                  handlerWidth: fabSize,
                  trackBar: FlutterSliderTrackBar(
                     activeTrackBar: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                     ),
                     activeTrackBarHeight: fabSize,
                     inactiveTrackBar: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                     ),
                     inactiveTrackBarHeight: fabSize,
                  ),
                  handler: FlutterSliderHandler(
                     child: FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  ),
               ),
               values: [sliderValue],
            ),
         ),
      ],
   ),
);
```

This code meet the requirements. Hope this helps! :)